# Do I have to create this relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I don't know .. if I have to create a relationship in this case or not ?

"**Devices**" table <--(0,1)------(relationship)-----(0.n)---> "**Types**" table

Knowing that :

1- **Types** table contains only few rows (3 or 4 rows !);

2- **Types** table will not be often updated.

Do I must create this table according to the standards, OR I put type value directly in Devices table ?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a one-to-many relationship. That is, any given Device can have at most one Type.

It's fine to add a column to the Devices table to indicate the device Type for the respective row.

If a given device might have multiple types, then you need the additional table in the middle to represent a many-to-many relationship.